# Using Javascript to highlight current page in navbar

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make a dynamic navigation bar that could identify the current page by highlighting the image buttons border that is related to the page it is on. For example, on the `index.html` the `homeButton.jpg` is highlighted. I would like this to be dynamic and not statically coded. I am using templates I would like the main content to be the only thing editable.

This is my HTML code for the navigation bar:

```
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href="../index.html" ><img id="theImg" src="../images/Buttons/homeBtn.jpg" name="homebtn" alt="Home" border="0" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="../pages/about.html"><img src="../images/Buttons/aboutBtn.jpg" alt="About" border="0" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="../pages/mediapages/media.html"><img src="../images/Buttons/mediaBtn.jpg" alt="Media" border="0" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="../pages/downloads.html"><img src="../images/Buttons/downloadBtn.jpg" alt="Download"  border="0" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="../pages/contactpages/contacts.html"><img src="../images/Buttons/contactBtn.jpg" alt="contact"  border="0" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="../pages/blog.html" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Buttons/blogBtn.jpg" alt="blog" border="0" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the JavaScript code:

```
var examplehtml = [['http://example.com/'],['http://www.example.com/']];
var navRoot = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByTagName("img");
var currentpage = document.location.href; 
if(currentpage == examplehtml [0] || currentpage == examplehtml [1] ){
  navRoot[0].src = "../images/Buttons/homeBtn2.jpg";
  return;
}

var indexpage = currentpage.search(/index.html/);
var aboutpage = currentpage.search(/about.html/)
var mediapage = currentpage.search(/mediapages/);
var downloadpage = currentpage.search(/downloads.html/);
var contactpage = currentpage.search(/contacts.html/);
var commentsentpage = currentpage.search(/comment_sent.html/);


if(indexpage>-1){navRoot[0].src = "../images/Buttons/homeBtn2.jpg";return;}
if(aboutpage>-1){navRoot[1].style.border='1px solid #fff';return;}
else if(mediapage>-1){navRoot[2].style.border='1px solid #fff';return;}
else if(downloadpage>-1){navRoot[3].style.border = '1px solid #fff';return;}
else if(contactpage>-1){navRoot[4].style.border='1px solid #fff';return;}
else if(commentsentpage>-1){navRoot[4].style.border = '1px solid #fff';return;}
}
window.onload = Getcurrentpage;
```

I was wondering is there a better way of doing this or anything I can do to improve performance?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Set your performance concern aside until you get your functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your JS and CSS separate; first off put that styling in the CSS:
CSS:

```
  .current {
    color:red; 
    border:1px solid red;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav>
```

JS:

```
var url = "http://example.com/products.html".split("/"); //replace string with location.href
var navLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
//naturally you could use something other than the <nav> element
var i=0;
var currentPage = url[url.length - 1];
for(i;i<navLinks.length;i++){
  var lb = navLinks[i].href.split("/");
  if(lb[lb.length-1] == currentPage) {
   navLinks[i].className = "current";

  }
  }
```

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/upewuh/edit#source).

Comment: @Sam glad to help; make sure to click the green check to mark as answer if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have presentational markup (e.g. borders) in your html.

You can use a unique id on each link and a matching class identifier on your body element and use CSS to apply the border style.

Although it's not exactly dynamic, something like:

HTML:

```
<body class="home">
```

```
<a href="home.html" id="home">
```

CSS:

```
.home a#home {

     border-color: red;
}
```

Your main challenge is getting the current page filename. It can get a bit sticky if you are/plan on using server-side scripting and have variables appended to your URL e.g ?p=45252463&x=234

I found this, should help:

http://www.richnetapps.com/automatically_highlight_current_page_in/

Comment: thanks for the reply. The main problem I had was splitting the location.href, now I know how to split properly to my situation the code is much smaller and has a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
  var domain = '{{ DOMAIN }}'; // www.example.com or dev.example.com
  var domain_index =  window.location.href.indexOf(domain);
  var long_app_name = window.location.href.slice(domain_index+domain.length+1); 
  // this turns http://www.example.com/whatever/whatever to whatever/whatever
  app_name = long_app_name.slice(0, long_app_name.indexOf('/')); 
  //now you are left off with just whatever
```

then you use jquery to add class active

```
$('nav a[href*="' + app_name+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

and of course the css:

```
.active{background:red;}
```

this works if you have your html like this:

```
<ul><li><a href="ee">ee</a></li><li><a href="dd">dd</a></li></ul>
```

this will atumatically add class active using the page url and color your background to red if your in www.somesite.com/ee thaen ee is the 'app' and it will be active

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<nav class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
    <a href="apply.html">Apply</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
</nav>
```

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
   if (document.links[i].href === document.URL) {
       document.links[i].className = 'current';
   }
}
```